# typescript react redux actions that return promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

in my react app, i like to hide redux implementation from View logic in its own package 'i call it sdk package', and i export set fo react's Hooks from sdk package so any client can use it.

#### Question in short.

> `const fetch = (params) => (dispatch) => api.get('/media', params);`
>   how can i tell typescript to skip the thunk and deal with the return value of thunk function
>   i have an Record object, how to type it to skip middle function ?

## Context

code:

```
// hook.tsx
import * as actions from './actions'; // thunks
import * as selectors from './selectors'; // reselect.
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

export function useMedia(): [Selectors<typeof selectors>,Actions<typeof actions>] {
  // use ref to cache hook
  return  useRef([
    bindSelectors(selectors, useSelector),
    bindDispatch(actions, useDispatch()),
  ]).current;
}
```

now inside my views, whenever i need to use that media slice i use.

```
import { useMedia } from '@sdk/media'

// ....
const [media, mediaActions] = useMedia();
// dispatch an action
mediaActions.fetch({limit:10}).then(console.log);
// select a slice using selector
const photos = media.photosOfAlbum(1);
```

my views doesnot know/care about how useMedia works, this way i could really split responsiblities inside my codebase, and ease codesharing, testing, etc.. since switching implementation anytime without affecting consumers of sdk (mobile/webapp/even nodejs apps) no one is aware that redux is powering sdk underhood.

problem is i cannot properly type these hooks .. (useMedia).

so we have 2 things to type here. the bindSelectors function and the bindDispatch function.

### bindSelectors

code

```
// @sdk/utils

function bindSelectors <T extends object>(selectors:T, useSelector): CurriedFunctionObject<T>{
  return new Proxy(selectors, {
    get: (main: T, key: keyof T, ctx: any) => {
      const fn = Reflect.get(main, key, ctx);

      // always inject store as first prop of fn
      // we get store arg from useSelector higher order (its already properly typed)
      return (props?: any) => useSelector(store => fn(store, props));
    },

}
```

this one i used to basicaly hack direct call on selector object asif first arg is always store.

```
export type CurriedFunctionObject<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends (
    s: import('../rootReducer').AppState,
    ...p: infer Ps
  ) => infer R
    ? (...p: Ps) => R
    : never;
};
```

now my selectors are bound and typed, my main problem is how to write Actions type..

### bindDispatch

it works alot like bindSelectors. and i use ActionCreatorsMapObject from 'redux-thunk' to type it

```
export function bindDispatch<T extends Record<string, any>>(
  obj: T,
  dispatch: Dispatch,
): ActionCreatorsMapObject<T> {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get: (main: T, key: keyof T, ctx) => {
      const fn = Reflect.get(main, key, ctx);

      return (...props: any[]) => dispatch(fn(...props));
    },
  });
}
```

### Problem with bindDispatch :-

if i dispatch a thunk that return a promise, its not typed correctly..

example above code `media.fetch({limit:10}).then///.then is will give error`Property 'catch' does not exist on type '(dispatch: any, getState: any, {  }: {  }) => any'`

so basically since fetch action looks like this

`const fetch = (params) => (dispatch) => api.get('/media', params);` so it expect a function `(dispatch)`, so how can i tell typescript to skip the thunk and deal with the return value of thunk function

Answer (score 0):

You could define something like this in your global.d.ts (or put it inside a separate redux.d.ts to separate it):

```
import { ThunkAction } from 'redux-thunk';
import { Action } from 'redux';

declare module 'redux' {
    export interface Dispatch<A extends Action = AnyAction> {
        <T extends ThunkAction<any, any, any, any>>(action: T): T extends ThunkAction<infer K, any, any, any> ? K : never;
    }
}
```